# boot fails with "cryptsetup: lvm fs found but no lvm configured" [dual boot(2xlinux LVM, dm-crypt+luks)]

Tags: linux, dual-boot, lvm, luks, dm-crypt

I have a dual-boot(xubuntu/#!) setup LVM with dm-crypt+luks as follows

```
/dev/sda1 = /boot (xubuntu)
/dev/sda2 = /boot (#!)
/dev/sda3 = encrypted LVM
  /dev/mapper/volgroup-xroot = / (xubuntu)
  /dev/mapper/volgroup-yroot = / (#!)
  /dev/mapper/volgroup-home  = /home (/home/xubuntu & /home/crunchbang)
  /dev/mapper/volgroup-swap  = swap
```

I have Grub installed only from xubuntu on the MBR

I was able to set this up successfully get this working initially. Recently, upon installing Libre Office on the xubuntu OS, I unwittingly let the network manager get uninstalled. I attempted to reinstall it by booting into crunchbang and then chroot-ing into the xubuntu file system. It worked but it messed the crunchbang boot process up somehow.

First Grub dropped the crunchbang OS listing. I updated it and it found it again. Now, when I attempt to boot crunchbang it seems to process everything fine up to requesting a passphrase. After entering my passphrase, it quickly  fails and reports the message "cryptsetup: lvm fs found but no lvm configured"
and reprompts for the passphrase again.

looking into it, I found this error message comes from the  /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot script and occurs when

```
 if [ "$FSTYPE" = "LVM_member" ] || [ "$FSTYPE" = "LVM2_member" ]; then
   if [ -z "$cryptlvm" ]; then
     message "cryptsetup: lvm fs found but no lvm configured"
     return 1
```

$FSTYPE is just the type of the dmname, the decrypted lvm container which is set as $cryptroot and then $crypttarget - apparently successfully in order to reach this error.

It seems like the script is checking for $cryptlvm to be an empty string and if so fails with my error. I have found only one reference to $cryptlvm, setting cryptlvm="" earlier in the cryptroot script, and no reference to it otherwise.

I have been checking things against my xubuntu install and all relevant files so far are equivalent, including setting cryptlvm="" at the beginning of the script.

And this is where I'm stuck.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make this message disappear by setting your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` with `crypt_opts=<whatever#1>,lvm=<whatever#2>`

The script in `/usr/share` you mention set the variable cryptlvm with .

For further reference, my own `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` contains:

```
crypt_opts=target=system,source=/dev/sda5,lvm=/dev/mapper/system
```

system is here my encrypted lvm partition.

Comment: Of course, you need to regenerate your `grub.cfg` with `grub-mkconfig` after this modification.